# Configure netbeans to deploy a web application in a real server

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I have an external Server consider its IP is `https://10.6.99.88:4949`

Now I want to deploy my web application directly to this server instead of `localhost:4848`, Is there any way to configure **Netbeans** to deploy this web application directly to the server, if yes how can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

First you have to enable securehub-admin on Glassfish:

```
asadmin change-admin-password
asadmin enable-secure-admin
asadmin stop-domain
asadmin start-domain
```

Then add a remote Glassfish Server in NetBeans (Choose Remote Domain when creating the server) and fill in the details for your server instance.

[image: glassfish remote server]

If it doesn't work, you may have to restart NetBeans and Glassfish again. IF you have a proxy configured in NetBeans, this could also cause problems with the connection.

**See also:**

- [NetBeans Wiki - Remote Glassfish](http://wiki.netbeans.org/RemoteGlassFish4)
- [Netbeans and Glassfish remote deployments](https://blog.e-beyond.de/2011/06/22/netbeans-and-glassfish-remote-deployments/)